# In the homework or on the homework

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition colocates with "homework"; "in" or "on"? Did you make many mistakes (in) or (on) your homework? I am upset because I made quite a few mistakes (in) or (on) my English homework.

Comment: Hello, M.Carlos. ELU has a requirement that questions be accompanied by reasonable evidence of personal research. What do raw Google searches for "mistakes in my homework" and "mistakes on my homework" seem to indicate?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you find mistakes **in** someone's/your homework.